# jquery load a div on top of another div and close it

Tags: jquery, html

I've a page with a a number of divs. I have a container div, and then a div for the the content and a div on the right with a menu.

The thing is, I have page which I would like to load on 'top' of the content div, si I basically want to get the dimensions of the content div, as the length of this can vary depending on what page you are on, and plonk another page to replace this page.

I also want to be able to close the 'new' window so the old content displays as it was prior to the new window being invoked.

Looking at the JQuery docs, am I right in assuming I have to use the prepend command? Not sure, but I think I also need a close function something like below?

```
$('.close').click(function (e) {
            //Cancel the link behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#my_new_page').hide();
        });
```

Comment: I can't visualize this without seeing your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this to make overlays:
http://jsfiddle.net/ULmdH/1/

Use this to close the overlay:

```
$('.close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.new_content').hide();
    //or
    $('.new_content').remove();
});
```

Comment: Awesome; thanks guys for answering; this is a great resource :) One thing I have noticed with your code is I cant seem to get the close button working if I have the close class inside the new_content. If I have it outside the in my aspx page, my close link works. PS I can't seem to put a carriage return without stackoverflow saving my edit. This is what doesnt work var new_content = $('<div id="new_content">lala</div><a href="#" class="close">Close</a>').width(old_content.width())
                                                                .height(old_content.height())

Comment: You should use `.live()` (or `.delegate()`/`.on()`) to attach the event or attach the click event after  `$('.container').append(new_content);`

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks :) . Its solved one problem for me - i.e. getting the overlay working on top of the div. However I should have been clearer in my oroginal post. I have a page which I am using the .get method to retrieve the contents and place it in my overlay, however I need to format the contents before I place it in the new_content. If the page Im reteiveing has already got formatting, is it possible  to suck all of this in and place it in the new_content? So far I've just got content, and am thinking of building the html/css around it before putting it in in the new content.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. But if the content you are retrieving allready is formatted you can place it on a container with `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the dimensions of the content div -

width = contentdiv.width();
height = contentdiv.height():

you could then overlay a div over the top of the content div using CSS z-index.

Perhaps you're looking for something like the fancybox plugin for Jquery? I've used that from time to time, it's pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @JK36 for what i understand you're looking for a lightbox or modal window. A great list [here](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/). Well [JQModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples) at example #5 you could get multi modals and 1010 has another [great implementation](http://www.onezerozeroone.com/examples/multimodal/).

Cheers!